# undefined index: plugins in /usr/share/phppgadmin/classes/

Tags: php, ubuntu-13.10, phppgadmin

After updating ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 In phppgadmin this error message appear

undefined index: plugins in /usr/share/phppgadmin/classes/PluginManager.php

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed the issue. The error occurs because the plugin index is not found in the array. So just simply replace line 34 with .

```
// Get the activated plugins
$plugins = !empty($conf['plugins'])?$conf['plugins']:[];
```

This will definitely solve your problem.

Cheers :)

Comment: It should be noted that the reason you didn't have this before was not due to the ubuntu version, but rather that the new version of PHP has [`E_NOTICE`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) enabled in [`error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading php, postgres and phpPgAdmin on a server, preserving my existing configuration file. After looking into the new pgAdmin config file template, I noticed this fragment:

```
    /** Plugins management
     * Add plugin names to the following array to activate them
     * Example:
     *   $conf['plugins'] = array(
     *     'Example',
     *     'Slony'
     *   );
     */
    $conf['plugins'] = array();
```

I copied it to my own configuration file (before the closing php tag) and all went fine, without any change to phpPgAdmin scripts.